# Only some files are unpacked while firmware reversing with binwalk tool

Tags: firmware, unpacking

I am reversing a firmware with binwalk. 
Unpacking was succeed, but I can't find my target files. (CGI files in www folder)
When I connect to the web page of my router, I can see links include CGI file names. 
But after unpacking, I can see only html files, I can't see CGI files.
I think only some files are unpacked with binwalk tools. 
How do you think what's the problem? 
Thank you

Comment: Adding a verbose output of binwalk / specific command line used for unpacking could prove helpful. some vendors may mess with packings / have semi-proprietary format so as it stands it's difficult to know whether it's a mis-usage or a format issue.

Comment: Sometimes, CGI files don't actually exist, and all of the HTTP backend is handled by one monolithic binary